# Drawing a primitive ( GL_QUADS ) on top of a 2D texture - no quad rendered, texture colour changed

Tags: c++, opengl, canvas, textures, render

I am trying to draw a 2D scene with a texture as background and then ( as the program flows and does computations ) draw different primitives on the "canvas". As a test case I wanted to draw a blue quad on the background image.

I have looked at several resources and SO questions to try get the information I need to accomplish the task ( e.g. [this tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/your_first_polygon/13002/) for first primitive rendering, [SOIL "example"](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) for texture loading ).

My understanding was that the texture will be drawn on Z=0, and quad as well. Quad would thus "cover" a portion of texture - be drawn on it, which is what I want. Instead the result of my display function is my initial texture in black/blue colour, and not my texture ( in original colour ) with a blue quad drawn on it. This is the display function code :

```
void display (void) {

glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// background render

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0f, 1024.0, 512.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.f); // window size is 1024x512

glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D ); 
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

glBegin (GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(0.0,0.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(1024.0,0.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(1024.0,512.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(0.0,512.0);
glEnd(); // here I get the texture properly displayed in window

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// foreground render

glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)winWidth / (GLfloat)winHeight, 1.0, 100.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glBegin (GL_QUADS);
glVertex2d(400.0,100.0);
glVertex2d(400.0,500.0);
glVertex2d(700.0,100.0);
glVertex2d(700.0,500.0);
glEnd(); // now instead of a rendered blue quad I get my texture coloured in blue

glutSwapBuffers();  }
```

I have already tried with many modifications, but since I am just beginning with OpenGL and don't yet understand a lot of it, my attempts failed. For example, I tried with pushing and popping matrices before and after drawing the quad, clearing the depth buffer, changing parameters in gluPerspective etc.

**How do I have to modify my code so it will render the quad properly on top of the background texture image of my 2D scene ?** Being a beginner, extra explanations of the modifications ( as well as mistakes in the present code ) and principles in general will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** - after answer by Reto Koradi :

I have tried to follow the instructions, and the modified code now looks like :

```
// foreground render

glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glOrtho(0.0f, 1024.0, 512.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.f);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glBegin (GL_QUADS); // same from here on
```

Now I can see the blue "quad", but it is not displayed properly, it looks something like this [image: like this].

Beside that, the whole scene is flashing really quickly.

**What do I have to change in my code so that quad will get displayed properly and screen won't be flashing ?**

Comment: Is your quad "clipping" the background texture? i.e. they're in the same Z position.

Comment: There's a difference between rendering the quad ON the texture, and rendering it in the same position as the texture.

Comment: disable depth testing when doing 2D.

Comment: @yngum - I don't have `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` anywhere in the code. But there is `glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);` in the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up a perspective transformation before rendering the blue quad:

```
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)winWidth / (GLfloat)winHeight, 1.0, 100.0);
```

The way `gluPerspective()` is defined, it sets up a transformation that looks from the origin down the negative z-axis, with the `near` and `far` values specifying the distance range that will be visible. With this transformation, z-values from -1.0 to -100.0 will be visible. Which does not include your quad at z = 0.0.

If you want to draw your quad in 2D coordinate space, the easiest solution is to not use `gluPerspective()` at all. Just use a `glOrtho()` type transformation like you did for your initial drawing.

If you want perspective, you will need a `GL_MODELVIEW` transformation as well. You can start with a translation in the negative z-direction, within a range of 1.0 to 100.0. You may have to adjust your coordinates for the different coordinate system as well, or use additional transformations that also translate in xy-direction, and possibly scale.

The code also has the coordinates in the wrong order for drawing the blue quad. You either have to change the draw call to `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` (recommended because it at least gets you one step closer to using features that are not deprecated), or swap the order of the last two vertices:

```
glBegin (GL_QUADS);
glVertex2d(400.0,100.0);
glVertex2d(400.0,500.0);
glVertex2d(700.0,500.0);
glVertex2d(700.0,100.0);
glEnd(GL_QUADS);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to follow your instructions, unfortunately with no success. Please see my edited(extended) question.

Comment: I added to the answer why the quad looks wrong. Not sure about the flashing. That's most likely an entirely different problem, and outside the scope of the original question.